# Using refs in Three JS useFrame hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-three-fiber

Using react-three-fiber often requires using refs to manipulate objects in the scene. For example, we might want to move a mesh's position on every frame render (see code below).

However, refs in typescript are always potentially undefined. So we have to check if our `meshRef` is current before we manipulate it:

```js
  useFrame((state) => {
    if (meshRef.current) {
      meshRef.current.position.add(new Vector3(1, 1, 1));
    }
  });
```

But I imagine that we want the code in our `useFrame` hook to be highly optimized. If we were using regular javascript react, there'd be no need for the `if(meshRef.current)`. So it seems that just by using typescript, we're sacrificing some performance.

Is there any way around this that doesn't involve telling the typescript compiler to ignore the potential undefined value? i.e `//@ts-ignore`

Full code example:

```js
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { Canvas, extend, useFrame, useThree } from "@react-three/fiber";
import "./styles.css";
import { Mesh, Vector3 } from "three";

const Scene = (): JSX.Element => {
  const meshRef = useRef<Mesh>();
  useFrame((state) => {
    if (meshRef.current) {
      meshRef.current.position.add(new Vector3(1, 1, 1));
    }
  });

  return (
    <Canvas camera={{ fov: 75, position: [0, 0, 70] }}>
      <mesh ref={meshRef}>
        <boxBufferGeometry args={[10, 10, 1]} />
      </mesh>
    </Canvas>
  );
};

export default Scene;
```

Comment: have you tried optional chaining? `useFrame(state => meshRef?.current?.position.add(...));`. Your linter or TS _might_ complain about expecting an expression though.

Comment: while I agree that this is a nicer syntax, but do you think it would perform any better? Doesn't it essentially require the same logic?

Comment: basically, but if there's a chance meshRef can be undefined you need to protect against that or it will throw an exception. Either catch the exception, or protect against undefined/null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `!` suffix to force treating an optional property as a required one.

```
const ref = useRef<{ someObj: true }>()
ref.current!.someObj // typescript allows this
```

However, this isn't type safe. And will definitely crash the first time it's run when the ref is `undefined`. But if you can be *absolutely sure* that this code only runs when the ref has a value, then it should work.

---

I wouldn't recommend it though. You're inviting a crash where you didn't realize that the value could actually be missing there.

The second reason I wouldn't recommend it is that this check you are trying to avoid is *really really* fast.

Checkout [this benchmark](https://jsben.ch/Aksiu) where it compares just doing the thing:

```
for (const obj of data) {
  result = result + obj.num;
}
```

and where you check for the presence of a thing and then do the thing:

```
for (const obj of data) {
  if (obj.num) {
    result = result + obj.num;
  }
}
```

On my machine, the second one is slower by less than 5%. And that's the worst case scenario of checking 1,000 times per loop. If you check the presence of a value just once per frame, the performance impact will be so miniscule.

In short, nullish checks like these are not why your webgl application is slow.