# Transform camera lookAt vector3 in only one axis

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm trying to save lookAtPos.x after i unpress left mouse button but lookAtPos resets to initial values

```
import React from 'react';
import { useFrame, useThree } from '@react-three/fiber';
import { Vector3, MathUtils } from 'three';

export default function Env(props) {
    const { pointer } = useThree();
    let lookAtPos = new Vector3( -0.5, 0.3, -0.5 );
    let camOffsetPos = new Vector3( 0, 0, 3 );
    let camNeedPos = new Vector3(); 
    let camCursorOffset = new Vector3();
    let mX = 0;

    useFrame((state, delta) => {
        state.camera.fov = 65;
        state.camera.near = 0.25;
        state.camera.far = 20;

        camNeedPos = lookAtPos.clone().add(camOffsetPos).add(camCursorOffset)

        state.camera.position.x += 3 * delta * (camNeedPos.x - state.camera.position.x)
        state.camera.position.y += 3 * delta * (camNeedPos.y - state.camera.position.y)
        state.camera.position.z += 3 * delta * (camNeedPos.z - state.camera.position.z)
        state.camera.lookAt(lookAtPos);

        let dX = pointer.x - mX;
        mX = pointer.x;
        if (props.cameraDragged) { // true when i press left mouse button
            lookAtPos.x -= dX; //i need to save lookAtPos.x
        }
        lookAtPos.x = MathUtils.clamp(lookAtPos.x, -1,1);
        camOffsetPos.x = -pointer.x * 0.5;
        camOffsetPos.y = -pointer.y * 0.15;

        console.log(lookAtPos)
    })

    return (
        <group></group>
    )
}
```

I'm just stucked. tried a lot of unclear solutions but non of them are played out...

Comment: Why don't you use some property like `state.camera.look` instead of local variable `lookAtPos`

Comment: I think you need lookAtPos to be a ref, have a look at this question and see if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70920345/using-refs-in-three-js-useframe-hook